# How do you handle EmptyResultDataAccessException with Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a situation where before I process an input file I want to check if certain information is setup in the database. In this particular case it is a client's name and parameters used for processing. If this information is not setup, the file import shall fail.

In many StackOverflow pages, the users resolve handling EmptyResultDataAccessException exceptions generated by queryForObject returning no rows by catching them in the Java code.

The issue is that Spring Integration is catching the exception well before my code is catching it and in theory, I would not be able to tell this error from any number of EmptyResultDataAccessException exceptions which may be thrown with other queries in the code.

Example code segment showing try...catch with queryForObject:

```
    MapSqlParameterSource mapParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();

    // Step 1 check if client exists at all
    mapParameters.addValue("clientname", clientName);
    try {
        clientID = this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(FIND_BY_NAME, mapParameters, Long.class);
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        SQLException sqle = (SQLException) e.getCause();
        logger.debug("No client was found");
        logger.debug(sqle.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return clientID;
```

In the above code, no row was returned and I want to properly handle it (I have not coded that portion yet). Instead, the catch block is never triggered and instead, my generic error handler and associated error channel is triggered instead.

Segment from file BatchIntegrationConfig.java:

```
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="errorChannel")
    public DefaultErrorHandlingServiceActivator errorLauncher(JobLauncher jobLauncher){
        logger.debug("====> Default Error Handler <====");
        return new DefaultErrorHandlingServiceActivator();
    }
```

Segment from file DefaultErrorHandlingServiceActivator.java:

```
public class DefaultErrorHandlingServiceActivator {
    @ServiceActivator 
    public void handleThrowable(Message<Throwable> errorMessage) throws Throwable {
        // error handling code should go here
    }
}
```

Tested Facts:

1. queryForObject expects a row to be returned and will thrown an
   exception if otherwise, therefore you have to handle the exception
   or use a different query which returns a row.
2. Spring Integration is monitoring exceptions and catching them before
   my own code can hand them.

What I want to be able to do:

- Catch the very specific condition and log it or let the end user know what they need to do to fix the problem.

Edit on 10/26/2016 per recommendation from @Artem:

Changed my existing input channel to Spring provided Handler Advice:

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "memberInputChannel", outputChannel = "commonJobGateway", adviceChain="handleAdvice")
```

Added support Bean and method for the advice:

```
    @Bean
ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice handleAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setOnFailureExpression("payload");
    advice.setFailureChannel(customErrorChannel());
    advice.setReturnFailureExpressionResult(true);
    advice.setTrapException(true);
    return advice;
}

private QueueChannel customErrorChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

I initially had some issues with wiring up this feature, but in the end, I realized that it is creating yet another channel which will need to be monitored for errors and handled appropriately. For simplicity, I have chosen to not use another channel at this time.

Answer (score 2):

Although potentially not the best solution, I switched to checking for row counts instead of returning actual data. In this situation, the data exception is avoided.

The main code above moved to:

```
    MapSqlParameterSource mapParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    mapParameters.addValue("clientname", clientName);

    // Step 1 check if client exists at all; if exists, continue
    // Step 2 check if client enrollment rules are available
    if (this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(COUNT_BY_NAME, mapParameters, Integer.class) == 1) {
        if (this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(CHECK_RULES_BY_NAME, mapParameters, Integer.class) != 1) return null;
    } else return null;

    return findClientByName(clientName);
```

I then check the data upon return to the calling method in Spring Batch:

```
        if (clientID != null) {
        logger.info("Found client ID ====> " + clientID);
    }
    else {
        throw new ClientSetupJobExecutionException("Client " + 
                fileNameParts[1] + " does not exist or is improperly setup in the database.");
    }
```

Although not needed, I created a custom Java Exception which could be useful at a later point in time.

Comment: Basically I feel there are multiple answers to this question depending on the needs of your organization. Spring Integration has provided methods to handle errors and they align well with documented design patterns. Do to this project being a proof of concept, I went with the above approach and changed the query. By doing so, I know exactly when the error happened and can respond accordingly. @Artem's solution is also valid below.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Integration Service Activator can be supplied with the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`, which works like a `try...catch` and let you to perform some logic `onFailureExpression`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice

Your problem might be that you `catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e)`, but it is a `cause`, not root on the `this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject()` invocation.

Comment: Updated original questions with error stack so that the exceptions can be reviewed in response to the last paragraph above.

Comment: OK. Reviewed. And what is the question? That is how it works. The `ClientDaoJDBC` throws `EmptyResultDataAccessException`. It is wrapped to the `MessageHandlingException`, and afterwards to the `MessageTransformationException` since you use `MemberFileMessageToJobRequest.messageToRequest()` as a `transformer` function.

Comment: I was referring to @Artem Bilan's comment about a problem with between cause and not root cause. I just wanted to make sure it was documented. I did try to catch all 3 exceptions but Spring Integration still gets the exception first.

Comment: Fully unclear where you try to catch them. According the stack trace there is no any `try...catch` (or it is for wrong Exception). That's why it is send as an `ErrorMessage` to the `errorChannel`. Please, rephrase what you want to have. Any non-`MessagingException` is wrapped to an appropriate `MessagingException`, because we need `failedMessage` to get a context for error.

Comment: In the original post, the catch statements for EmptyResultDataAccessException are in the sections commented step 1 and step 2. That is where I expected to catch them. I would prefer to gracefully handle the situation instead of heading down the error channel. But if I do have to head down the error channel, I would like to know specially why the exception occurred. In my case, the client was not setup or the client processing rules were not setup.

Comment: OK. That's why I suggested you to take a look into `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` and `try...catch` exceptions Spring Integration way. That isn't `errorChannel` model, but you can send `onFailureExpression` result to the `failureChannel` for further logic.

Comment: I have added additional code changes above and tested. Unfortunately, the logic still did not fire. I looked through many of your other comments on SO also. It seems like a valid solution but it is just not working yet.

Comment: When you ask DB for exactly one row, that is natural that a `EmptyResultDataAccessException` is thrown when there is no data. See `DataAccessUtils.requiredSingleResult(results)`. You are confusing me. I'm glad that you have found at least some solution for your task, but I don't see how to help you since all the info provided is in a mess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126762/discussion-between-tony-edwards-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: Based on our chat today, I was able to dig into the solution further and was able to understand the design you have offered. I have attempted to clean up the original post based on some of your comments above and confusion during our chat session.